# Matching based on patern in one of two files - Linux

Tags: linux, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I have two files of different formats and number of records. I'd like to search for lines in File2 based on the records in File1 and save the entire matched line(s) from File2 in a new file. The file examples are below:

*Input File 1*

```
991888
16889000
567899
....
....
```

*Input File 2*

```
16889000    xxxx    yyyy
687398793
5778
567899      aaaa    bbbb
999178
.....
```

*Output file*

```
16889000    xxxx    yyyy
567899      aaaa    bbbb
```

I've tried playing with various grep options, but no luck. Any help to solve this using out of the box tools would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: If normal tools don't work, I bet you have DOS line feeds in at least one of your files.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if (NF > 0) a[FNR""] = $0; next}; {for (x in a) {if ($1 ~ a[x]) {print}}}' input_file1.txt input_file2.txt
```